# I can't show the text using v-for

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a small project using VueJS, i try to loop over `body variable`  but i don't see the names between `<td></td>`

this my code :

```
<tr v-for="(row, i) in body" :key="`row-${i}`">
    <td v-for="(field, j) in mappedFields" :key="`mfield-${j}`">
         {{row[field]}} -
    </td>
</tr>
```

but when i do `body.name` it work.

This is my body variable :

```
{
    name: ["amine", "bill"],
    adress: ["montreal", "new york"]
    company: ["apple", "microsoft"]
    email: ["my@gmail.com", "john@microsoft.com"]
    phone: [5497821445449, 559485556555]
}
```

Comment: body is object not array. You should check body again. It must be array.

Comment: @BìnhTrương can you help me please, i spent hours on that :(

Comment: To simple you can use v-for="(row, i) in [body]". But I dont want what you want to show . Maybe it is simple than use v-for

Comment: @BìnhTrương  i get now ["amine", "bill"]   how can i iterate again :)

Comment: What is your purpose ? How do you want to show information ?

Comment: showing the names vertically now :)

Comment: {{row[field]}}    is one show me a list now like   ["amine", "bill"]    .
 i want to have like that 
 - Amine
-   Bill

Comment: You can use join() in javascript ,Example row[field].joint(""). Or You can continue use v-for second times

Comment: @BìnhTrương
i want to loop vertically over row[field] .    each one i a <tr>  like that 
<tr>
    <td>Amine</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>bill</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <template v-for="(field) in mappedFields">
    <tr v-for="(val, j) in body[field]" :key="j">
      <td>{{ val }} -</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</table>
```

Maybe it help you .

Comment: now i see addresses + names +emails + phones in the same table column not separated

Comment: You want to separated addresses, names, emails in other table right ?

Comment: each one in his column

Comment: Can you show the image what you want to show, I can not image what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

'body' here is not an array. You don't need to use v-for.
you can directly write

{{body.name}}

It will give you this: ["amine", "bill"]
Further if you want these values you can go for;

{{body.name[0]}} and
{{body.name[1]}}